# Install Linux package on launch when deploying Airflow with Helm in Azure Kubernets Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install Airflow on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Helm. I've found some guides to do so, and with some difficulty I've managed to get it working fine. I was now trying to run some DAGs I made and in one of those DAGs I use the bash operator to run a specific command, and that command needs a Linux package that does not come with the default image Helm uses for Airflow...
https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow

Is there a way to include extra Linux packages for the Helm Airflow chart installation? I've looked all over for it but couldn't find anything

Hope someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm itself is a templating language. Most of the helm charts give you a flexibility to change your base image of the applications. As long as you are using the related image, the helm chart will create a correct deployment for you.

In your case, if you want to extend the functionalities or install more packages in the base image, you will need to create your own image and push to an image repository.

For example, you can install your package like this with `Dockerfile` defined locally.

```
FROM apache/airflow:1.10.12-python3.6

RUN apt update && \
    apt install vim -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then, run the following command to build and upload your custom image.

```sh
docker build -t my-account/my-airflow:latest .
docker push my-account/my-airflow:latest
```

In your values file, you can specify your image name and tag then.

```yaml
airflow:
  image:
    repository: my-account
    tag: my-airflow
```

Once you apply this values file, helm will help you to change the default image to your customized one.

The tutorial in the [doc](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow#option-3---container-image) also mentions the custom image but it is for the DAG building. But with the same technique, you can customize your own base image.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes that sounds like a smart and tidy solution. I'll have to look into it then, I'm very new with Kubernetes and Docker, I haven't even interacted with Docker yet, just this deployment using Helm and was looking for an easy way to do this since my deadlines are kinda strict. Looking how to do all that may take some time but it is what it is. Thank you so much once again

Comment: You cannot separate the container runtime, which is docker in this case, from Kubernetes and helm. Helm is a templating language to Kubernetes and docker is the runtime for Kubernetes. In case you want to play around with Kubernetes, you will first know how the container works and how to build the container images. My suggestion is to understand the basic of Kubernetes and container before playing around with helm.

Comment: Hm I followed what you suggested. I created an account in hub.docker and built a custom airflow image using your exact code, I didn't change it to the actual package I need. I just had to add USER root before the apt install. It built successfully and I uploaded it to hub.docker. I then changed the values.yaml as you said, it is reaching the image I published, which is cool. But when I install it with (helm install "airflow" airflow-stable/airflow --namespace "airflow" --values ./values.yaml), the pods go into CrashLoopBackOff and Error and it doesn't work. I have no idea why

Comment: I saw the logs of the pods to see why they were failing and it failed on executing airflow it seems with the error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argcomplete'; which is a python dependency. Which is very weird since I'm supposedly using the same base image Helm was using, just adding my Linux package... If I try to include pip install argcomplete in the Dockerfile, it will say that it is already there as expected. Might it have to do with what user gets set as default after I extend the Airflow image?